# If statement is not working in phpmailer service

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

I'm setting a phpmailer service in which I'm just sending a link access to some users. The service works perfectly. My problem comes out when I set a IF statement and it doesn't validate. I just want that it can enter to the if validation. The validation to make is when, $result=='s' is true, send the mail, else ($result=='n'), do nothing.

I've researched a lot about this error, obviously not solution found.
This is for a mobile app built in ionic 3 with TypeScript and PHP services in Apache server. Also I use a connection to a MySQL DB.

```
{
<?php

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
header('Content-type: application/json');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, content-type, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-headers');

include('conecction.php');


use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'phpMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpMailer/src/SMTP.php';


$id =$request->id;


$counting = count($request->people);

for($i=0;$i<$counting ;$i++){

    $name=$request->people[$i]->name;
    $email=$request->people[$i]->mail;
    $hash=md5($id.$email);

$sql="select assisted from assistance where mail= '$email' and idmeeting = '$id'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

 if($result == 's'){

$mail = new PHPMailer;
  
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4; 
   
$mail->setFrom('noresponder@Prueba.com', 'Prueba MeetCoomeva');
$mail->addAddress($email, $name); 


$mail->Subject = 'Subject'; 

$mail->Body    = "Message Body "

}
if ($mail->send()) {
 $response['message']="Sent.";
} else { 
   echo "Sending error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
}
```

I want the service compose and send the mail when it have made the validation $result=='s'

I getting a 500 server internal error just by this. I just want it sends the mail when the validation is true or do nothing when entered in else.

Comment: You have to `fetch` the data, all you have now is a result set, not the actual data.  Even when you fetch it will be an array etc... I don't use Mysqli much these days, I could tell you how to do it with PDO.  But I am heading out the door as they say.

Comment: hi ArtisticPhoenix. Thank you so much for answering so quick. Speaking of, I don't have fetched before. Can you help me here, please?

Comment: You have a syntax error here `$mail->Body    = "Message Body "` missing the `;` and a set of `{ }` that are outside the PHP tags.  `{ <?php .... ?> }` - the missing `;` will cause the WSOD (white screen of death) without error reporting being on.  AKA you will just get a blank page.

Comment: You also have the typical SQL Injection issues ....   `where mail= '$email'`  you shouldn't put Variables directly in a query, you should use prepared statements.  For now that's the least of your problems, but for production code I would look into prepared statements.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help. The issue was already solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't enough:

```
$sql="select assisted from assistance where mail= '$email' and idmeeting = '$id'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

 if($result == 's'){
```

`$result` contains an instance of [mysqli_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php), not a simple string, so comparing it with `s` will never match. You need to [fetch the row](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) from the result set first, like this:

```
$sql="select assisted from assistance where mail= '$email' and idmeeting = '$id'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_row();

 if($row[0] == 's'){
```

Comment: I'll try. Thank you very much

Comment: Sadly, it still crashing. I tried _fetch_row()_  and _fetch_assoc()_  .Gonna work with this info. Thanks for the help

Comment: You need to define “crashing”